# Retrieve the value of a linked status field using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a `Vendor` entity with `statusId` field:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('Vendors', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            // other properties
            statusId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: {
                    model: 'VendorStatuses',
                    key: 'id'
                },
                onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
                onDelete: 'SET NULL'
            },
            // other properties
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('Vendors');
    }
};
```

that's linked to the corresponding `VendorStatus`:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
    up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable('VendorStatuses', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
        });
    },
    down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('VendorStatuses');
    }
};
```

The `Vendor` model has the association:

```
Vendor.belongsTo(models.VendorStatus, { foreignKey: 'statusId'})
```

How can I get Sequelize to generate the equivalent of:

```
SELECT "Vendor"."id", "Vendor"."name", 
    "VendorStatus"."name" AS "status"
FROM "Vendors" AS "Vendor"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "VendorStatuses" AS "VendorStatus"
    ON "Vendor"."statusId" = "VendorStatus"."id";
```

Basically, I want to have the `status` field filled with `VendorStatus.name` in the JSON result I return to the client.

I tried:

```
    const attribs = ['id', 'name', 'email', ['VendorStatus.name', 'status']];
    const vendors = await models.Vendor.findAll({ attributes: attribs, include: [models.VendorStatus] });
```

but that gives me the error `column "VendorStatus.name" does not exist`. Generated SQL is:

```
SELECT "Vendor"."id", 
       "Vendor"."name", 
       "Vendor"."email", 
       "vendorstatus.name"   AS "status", 
       "VendorStatus"."id"   AS "VendorStatus.id", 
       "VendorStatus"."name" AS "VendorStatus.name" 
FROM   "vendors" AS "Vendor" 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "vendorstatuses" AS "VendorStatus" 
                    ON "Vendor"."statusid" = "VendorStatus"."id"
```

Versions are:

```
[Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to get name attribute of `VendorStatus` table as `status`.

```
const vendors = await models.Vendor.findAll({ attributes: ['id', 'name', 'email'], include: [{ model: models.VendorStatus, attributes: [['name', 'status']] }] });
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it brings me close to what I want: `'VendorStatus.status': 'UNAPPROVED'`, but not all the way there (which may not be possible without writing a raw query).